# how to add database images to background of dynamical buttons

Tags: android

Am new in android,can anyone tell the procedure to  add background images to a dynamical button.here is my code for retriving json and creating button.i added image_url is my dadabase column and i added image name as imge.png.now am getting the image string.,i dont know how to retrieve images.

```
                    JSONArray jsonMainNode1 = jsonResponse.getJSONArray("menu");

                 int lengthJsonArr = jsonMainNode1.length(); 
                   for(int i=0; i <lengthJsonArr; i++)
                  {                                     
                      JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode1.getJSONObject(i);



                          String Pid      = jsonChildNode.optString("pid".toString());
                          String Name     = jsonChildNode.optString("name").toString();
                          String Refid=jsonChildNode.optString("refid".toString());
                          String image     = jsonChildNode.optString("image_url").toString();


                          OutputData = Name+image;  
                        str_id = Pid;

                     LinearLayout buttonContainer=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.btn_container);
                   Button button = new Button(buttonContainer.getContext());

                   button.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                   ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = button.getLayoutParams();
                   //Button new width
                   params.width = 64;
                   params.height = 64;
                   button.setLayoutParams(params);
                   button.setText(OutputData);
                   button.setTag(Refid);
                   button.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FEFCFF"));
                   button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_color);

                   button.setBackgroundDrawable(ImgDrawableFromFile(
                            getResources(), "/data/data/com.example.proj2/images"));



                   buttonContainer.addView(button);         

                   button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                           public void onClick(View v) {
                               LinearLayout buttonContainer = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.btn_container);
                               buttonContainer.removeAllViews();
                               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                        "button" +v.getTag()+ "is clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                               new LongOperation().execute("http://10.0.2.2:80/android_connect/home2.php?pid="+v.getTag());       


                           }
                           public Drawable ImgDrawableFromFile(Resources res, String file_path) {
                                File imgFile = new File(file_path);
                                if (imgFile.exists()) {

                                    myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
                                    if (myBitmap != null)
                                        return new BitmapDrawable(res, myBitmap);
                                    else
                                        return null;
                                }
                                return null;

                            }

                            }



                       );

                  }
                }
                }

               //if closing bracket                       
                catch (JSONException e) {

                      e.printStackTrace();
                   }

                 }

        }

        private Drawable ImgDrawableFromFile(Resources resources, String string) {

            return null;
        }

        }
public void newclick(View v){

    Button backbutt=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    backbutt.setTag(str_id);
    LinearLayout buttonContainer = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.btn_container);
       buttonContainer.removeAllViews();

    new LongOperation().execute("http://10.0.2.2:80/android_connect/home2.php?rid="+ v.getTag());    

    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"button"+ v.getTag() + "is clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    //LinearLayout back_button = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.butt_layout);





}
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: upload your new code. What u implemented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way: Create `Drawable` like below:

```
button.setBackgroundDrawable(ImgDrawableFromFile(
                            getResources(), your image path)
```

and load image from `Storage`:

```
public Drawable ImgDrawableFromFile(Resources res, String file_path) {
    File imgFile = new File(file_path);
    if (imgFile.exists()) {

        myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
        if (myBitmap != null)
            return new BitmapDrawable(res, myBitmap);
        else
            return null;
    }
    return null;

}
```

and if you want to load images from `Assets` then used below:

```
private Drawable getBitmapFromAsset(Resources res,String strName)
{
 AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
 InputStream istr = null;
 try {
 istr = assetManager.open(strName);
 } catch (IOException e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
}

Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(istr);  
if (bitmap != null) 
 return new BitmapDrawable(res, bitmap);
 else 
 return null;
}
```

Comment: for image path,where i store image?

Comment: Then first u need to copy that Image from `Asstes` to `internal storage("/data/data/your_package/image_folder")` and then used my above function to load image

Comment: i did the same,but now my button is not visible

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46510/discussion-between-m-d-and-ammu)

Comment: i got the image from internal storage and i added to button,but i have 4 button same image only added to all the button.how to retrive corresponding image to each button

Comment: YES.I have 4 button and each button i stored image in database.